Logitech MX Keys with USB receiver no longer working on Ubuntu 24.04
I have a logitech MX Keys keyboard, connected via a USB dongle to my computer.
It works fine on Windows, it works fine during boot. It uses to work fine on Ubuntu.
Yet, a few days ago, it stopped working on Ubuntu. No real explanation.
I can still boot, select Linux, I can still login,
and once the X session is active, then the keyboard stops working.
Note that I can instead start a console session, in which case, there is no problem, the keyboard works fine.
Looking into great depth of configuration files,
it seems that the keyboard is being reclassified as "touchpad" somewhere.
And then the keyboard doesn't work anymore.
A virtual keyboard appears on screen instead, but for most application, it doesn't work, making the computer useless.
I tried many ways to fix this issue, to no avail.
Lastly, I could make the computer start on XFCE instead of default ubuntu gnome, and now the keyboard works correctly. Not exactly a perfect outcome, but a work around, and a pretty good hint that something is fishy with gnome.
Anyone having met a similar issue?
